# My minitube stopped playing, any suggestions why?

Tags: video, youtube, minitube

My minitube program suddenly stopped playing, frozen sound and video. Any suggestions why this happened. I am using Ubuntu 11.10. I uninstalled and reinstalled minitube, but still the same.

Comment: I just tried it out. It's crashing for me, too. A bug, probably, and as such off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

[This is a well-known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/minitube/+bug/1057718). A new version is [on its way](http://flavio.tordini.org/minitube-1-9).

**Edit**: Minitube 1.9 has already been pushed out [on the webupd8 test ppa](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/test). Shouldn't been long before its available from the [main webupd8.org PPA](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/webupd8).

Related questions you should read before installing from a PPA:

[What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

[Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)